# Emails with SendGrid Web API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I'm following this tutorial: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby/. Very straightforward. However, I want to avoid having a big chunk of code in my controller to send an email. It currently looks like this:

```
from = Email.new(email: 'some@email.com')
to = Email.new(email: 'some@email.com')
subject = 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun'
content = Content.new(type: 'text/plain', value: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Ruby')
mail = Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)

sg = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: 'key')
response = sg.client.mail._('send').post(request_body: mail.to_json)
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to trigger it from a service like: `SendMail.new.perform()` or some nice one-liner in the controller.

How would I abstract this code away from the controller and how would I call that new service/abstraction?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

You can absolutely extract that from your controller, this is normally described as a [service object](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/refactor-ruby-rails-service-object/).

I like to keep service objects in the app folder. You can do so by creating the directory `app/services`. Then create a file for the class, `app/services/email_service.rb` for example. In that file add the code to send the email, maybe something like this:

```rb
class EmailService
  def self.call(from:, to:, subject:, content:)
    self.new.send_email(from: from, to: to, subject: subject, content: 
  end

  def initialize()
    @sendgrid = SendGrid::API.new(api_key: Rails.application.credentials.sendgrid)
  end

  def send_email(from:, to:, subject:, content:)
    from = Email.new(email: from)
    to = Email.new(email: to)
    content = Content.new(type: 'text/plain', value: content)
    mail = Mail.new(from, subject, to, content)
    response = @sendgrid.client.mail._('send').post(request_body: mail.to_json)
  end
end
```

You can then call this service from your controller with the one liner:

```rb
EmailService.call(from: "me@mydomain.com", to: "you@yourdomain.com", subject: "My new email service", content: "It's pretty wonderful")
```

As a bonus, it's also easier to unit test the `EmailService` separate to the controller and to mock it out in controller tests.

Comment: Thanks for this! Any thoughts on how to set the content to be a mailer view (as in ActionMailer) and I18n translation?

Comment: @Spätzle I’d probably look at [the SendGrid-actionmailer integration](https://github.com/eddiezane/sendgrid-actionmailer) to solve this through Action Mailer.

Comment: The SMTP solution did not work for some reason. I have finally found a workaround which solves my problem - essentially rendering the mail using the old mailer (which did support I18n), taking the `body.raw_source` and putting it as the `content` argument in your solution.

Comment: I don’t understand, neither of my suggestions included SMTP. Glad you got things sorted though.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using rails, you can define it in your environment file and use one line code to send email from your controller.

production.rb

```rb
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
   # Defaults to:
   # config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
   #   location: '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
   #   arguments: '-i'
   # }
   config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
   config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
   config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'no-reply@example.com'}
```

and in your controller

```rb
   mail( :to => @user.email,
    :subject => 'Thanks for signing up for our amazing app' )
```

best case for using sendmail is using it with an ActionMailer class. You can look it up at rails documentation.